# How can I handle filenames with Arabic text in Windows?

Tags: c++, filenames, handle, arabic

I got this source code from somewhere on the Net.  It searches for files on the hard disk and prints out the path of the files:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>



int SearchDirectory(std::vector<std::string> &refvecFiles,
                    const std::string        &refcstrRootDirectory,
                    const std::string        &refcstrExtension,
                    bool                     bSearchSubdirectories = true)
{
  std::string     strFilePath;             // Filepath
  std::string     strPattern;              // Pattern
  std::string     strExtension;            // Extension
  HANDLE          hFile;                   // Handle to file
  WIN32_FIND_DATA FileInformation;         // File information


  strPattern = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\*.*";

  hFile = ::FindFirstFile(strPattern.c_str(), &FileInformation);
  if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    do
    {
      if(FileInformation.cFileName[0] != '.')
      {
        strFilePath.erase();
        strFilePath = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\" + FileInformation.cFileName;

        if(FileInformation.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
          if(bSearchSubdirectories)
          {
            // Search subdirectory
            int iRC = SearchDirectory(refvecFiles,
                                      strFilePath,
                                      refcstrExtension,
                                      bSearchSubdirectories);
            if(iRC)
              return iRC;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          // Check extension
          strExtension = FileInformation.cFileName;
          strExtension = strExtension.substr(strExtension.rfind(".") + 1);

          if(strExtension == refcstrExtension)
          {
            // Save filename
            refvecFiles.push_back(strFilePath);
          }
        }
      }
    } while(::FindNextFile(hFile, &FileInformation) == TRUE);

    // Close handle
    ::FindClose(hFile);

    DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
    if(dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
      return dwError;
  }

  return 0;
}


int main()
{
  int                      iRC         = 0;
  std::vector<std::string> vecAviFiles;
  std::vector<std::string> vecTxtFiles;


  // Search 'c:' for '.avi' files including subdirectories
  iRC = SearchDirectory(vecAviFiles, "d:", "doc");
  if(iRC)
  {
    std::cout << "Error " << iRC << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  // Print results
  for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator iterAvi = vecAviFiles.begin();
      iterAvi != vecAviFiles.end();
      ++iterAvi)
    std::cout << *iterAvi << std::endl;

  // Search 'c:\textfiles' for '.txt' files excluding subdirectories
  /*
  iRC = SearchDirectory(vecTxtFiles, "c:\\textfiles", "txt", false);
  if(iRC)
  {
    std::cout << "Error " << iRC << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  // Print results
  for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator iterTxt = vecTxtFiles.begin();
      iterTxt != vecTxtFiles.end();
      ++iterTxt)
    std::cout << *iterTxt << std::endl;

  // Wait for keystroke
  _getch();
  */

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when it finds a filename with Arabic text, it doesn't display it correctly; It just shows `"?????????????????????"`.  I need the file path to send to a server.  Is there anyway to solve the problem?

**UPDATE:**
I have revised the code.

The new code is as follows:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace bf = boost::filesystem;
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string e_string = "Error";
int main()
{
    string fileName = "C:\\حم.txt";
    string destination = "D:\\log.txt" ;
    bf::path fileCopied(fileName);
    bf::path fileCopiedDestination (destination);
    if (!bf::exists(fileCopied) )
    {
        cerr << e_string;
    }
     if (!bf::exists(fileCopiedDestination))
        {
        cerr << e_string;
    }
    try
    {
        bf::copy_file(fileCopied,fileCopiedDestination);
    }
    catch(std::exception e)
    {
        cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

This code compiles, but I get this error:

```
ErrorErrorstd::exception
```

Also, the copying process fails.

I tried to change this line:
`string fileName = "C:\\حم.txt";`

to:
`string fileName = "C:\\??.txt";`

but in vain.

How can I copy this file?

Comment: i need to search arabic filname
if i get the string and pass it to another function is the arabic filename cause problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're "just a beginner", so I strongly suggest this: download [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) and use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm). It has a class `boost::filesystem::path` that represents a filename. It's all you should use for dealing with filenames. Use the Boost.Filesystem functions for searching for files, and use the `boost::filesystem::path` object and the special `iostreams` in Boost.Filesystem to open those files.

Printing Unicode-encoded strings to the console window is... not easily done in Windows.

Comment: i don't need to print unicode character but i want to get the ablility to copy this kind of filename to another place CopyFile doesn't help
so what i must do to solve this problem ????

Comment: @user1203062: How does `filesystem::copy_file` not help? It copies files. If you're talking about renaming a file, that's `filesystem::rename`, which also effectively moves it.

Comment: i talked about the CopyFile member function of the windows.h API
the problem this API can't handle arabic file
it can't copy file that contain arabic text in the filename 
when i look at GetLastERROR() return message File doesn't exist
so how can i such file

Comment: @user1203062: I'm telling you to not use the Win32 functions. Instead use the Boost.Filesystem functions for dealing with file access and manipulation.

Comment: can the boost.filesystem handle arabic filename ?

Comment: @user1203062: Why would I have suggested it otherwise?

Comment: @user1203062: *What* doesn't work? What is your code? How did it not work? Why don't you take the code and post a new question, or augment your question with your Boost.Filesystem-based code?

Comment: scroll the page up and see the new code of copying files using boost library as do you say that the boost library will solve the problem otherwise it still the same problem i can't copy the file with arabic name.

Answer (score 2):

If your OS is Windows, using 8-bit characters to name files is a bad idea; it will restrict you to the so-called "ANSI code page" (itself something of a misnomer).  Define `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` and use Windows APIs that accept `PWSTR`.  This will allow you to have unicode filenames.

If you need to write portable code, you may need to partition your code into portable and non-portable parts.  When calling the actual file APIs you would then convert from a saner encoding (UTF-8?) to the platform-specific filename (`PWSTR` in the case of Windows; you can do this with `MultiByteToWideChar` and `CP_UTF8` as the source code page).

Comment: i don't understand clearly because i'm just a beginner
what i must change in this code to use the UTF-8

Comment: @user1203062 - The "Windows way" is to just use `WCHAR` everywhere.  The UTF-8 suggestion is only if you need to write portable code.  Now that you edited your question with additional code I can surmise you don't care about portability (since you use Win32 calls), my suggestion is to just `#define UNICODE`/`#define _UNICODE` and use `wstring` instead of `string`.

Comment: doesn't compile even where is the problem